# Sample edge attribute in NetworkX using Python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to sample three edge attributes from a directed graph I built with networkX. The edges in the graph with the attribute 'dependency' are listed below:

```
import networkx as nx
import random
from random import choice
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge('x','a', dependency=0.4)
G.add_edge('x','b', dependency=0.6)
G.add_edge('a','c', dependency=1)
G.add_edge('b','c', dependency=0.3)
G.add_edge('b','d', dependency=0.7)
G.add_edge('d','e', dependency=1)
G.add_edge('c','y', dependency=1)
G.add_edge('e','y', dependency=1)
```

Now I want to sample three different edge attributes from above and multiply them with a random number between 0 and 1. It should look somehow like this:

```
for i in range(3):
    sampled_edge = random.sample(G.edges, 1)
    sampled_edge_with_random_number = sampled_edge['dependency'] * random.uniform(0,1)
    print(sampled_edge_with_random_number)
```

But I keep getting the following error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `random.sample` works only if you `import random`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two mistakes in your script.

1. What is `random.sample(G.edges, 1)`? Definitely it's list that contains one item therefore it can't be a key for any edge. Correct key is `sampled_edge[0]`
2. What is `sampled_edge`? If it's list or tuple, it can't have any keys. 
   The only thing that should have a key is EdgeView of your graph. It should be `G.edges` then.

After you identify some edge, you can access its atributes too. So just replace your `sampled_edge['dependency']` with `G.edges[sampled_edge[0]]['dependency']` in your script and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation - I understood. And the proposed solution worked as well, thanks for this too!